# iOS custom font limit

Tags: ios, fonts, limit, max

I was creating an app and noticed that I couldn't add any more than 125 fonts before the app started crashing when I ran it on the phone, it always runs fine in the simulator. It complained that it couldn't find resources like images, xib files, etc. I created a test app with a completely different set of fonts and it crashed when the font count got to 124. I looked at the memory usage of the app on the phone and it was fine. Is there a limit to the number of custom fonts that can be put in an app? Any ideas?